# Intermittent fasting - losing more muscle than fat

Tags: weight-loss, muscle-gain, intermittent-fasting

I've started intermittent fasting a week ago. First eating 8am, last 4-5pm, limited to 1800 kcals, around 100g carbs, 70g fat, and 190g protein. I'm 94kgs, 172cm, with 19.6% body fat at the moment, with a workout plan composed of 4 days weight lifting, 2 days cardio (25km cycling), 1 day free weight workout (abs, lower back). According to my tracker, burning approx 3300 kcals a day.

In the first few days 0.2kg dropped per day, now 0.1kg per day. This would be an excellent (almost too much) progress, however, the scale shows that most of it lost from muscle, and only minimal amount of fat lost.

Not sure if it's because of fasting (I was suspicious when I first read about it - it's completely against all of my knowledge get from my 6 years body building experience), but I must do something wrong if my results are the opposite of what it's promising.

Comment: I’m voting to reopen this question. It is not about nutrition, it’s clearly about understanding how to manage body composition. Because that is a goal of physique athletes and others as well, I believe that this qualifies as being on topic here.

Comment: Maybe cutting down the carb will help. I'm facing similar problems but I'm not even losing any major weight in the first place, but reducing carb consumption somewhat helped me.

Comment: I'm losing weight, maybe even faster than I should, the issue is that I'm losing more muscles than fat

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi - Carb cutting in the absence of a calorie deficit only depletes the body's glycogen stores which WILL result in weight loss, but that weight is water and not fat. It will come back literally as soon as carbs are returned to normal. Such an effort is meaningless. Fat loss occurs on a per need basis and insufficient calories create that need.

Comment: @JustSnilloc thanks for the info. I'm very new to this. The calorie-deficit diet was not working for me, but reducing carb resulted in some weight loss. So, maybe this loss won't last very long :(